# How to display a template/redirect to a template after processing a django signal?

Tags: django, paypal, django-paypal

I'm trying to integrate django-paypal, and I need to process a successful or failed signal.

I've got all my code done, but I now need to display a template telling the user their payment has succeeded or failed.

If I `return HttpResponseRedirect...` nothing happens, and I can't render_to_response because I don't have access to the context (and I'm using sekazai or something).

How can I do this?

```
## Called when django-paypal fails to validate PDT data
def pdt_failed_transaction(sender, **kwargs):
    return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('payment-error'))
```

Answer (score 2):

Short answer: you can't. This isn't what signals are designed for. You'll need to work the validation code into your form and handle the responses in your view. That's the process.

Answer (score 0):

Came across this question through a Google search and found the response pretty useless/unhelpful.  I think this is a valid curiosity, and while Chris Pratt is correct that you cannot modify the request or response in signals, it does seem reasonable to want to run some code based on a user having just logged in.

To run some code only when someone logs in that contains a redirect, you can use an intermediary view and the LOGIN_REDIRECT_URL setting in your settings.py https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/settings/#login-redirect-url

in settings.py:

```
LOGIN_REDIRECT_URL = reverse_lazy('app.views.after_login')
```

in app/views.py:

```
@login_required
def after_login(request):
    if conditions met:
        return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('home_alt'))
    else:
        return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('home'))
```